# Hovering over one list item effects every list item also

Tags: html, css, sass

While trying to make a social bar `side-menu` I added a hover effect when if hovered the list item would pop out to the left. But for some reason when hovering any list item every other pops out also. I was searching for a solution but sadly didn't find the answer to this problem.

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/IMiljancic/pen/qvZKMb)

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 solutions :

1. Apply the hover property for the link instead of the li item.
2. Build a css class for width & margin-left and use jQuery to load it once li item is hovered.

I've made a fast jQuery function :

```
$('.social-nav-item').hover(function(){

   $(this).addClass("link_hovered");

});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QoNXZL

Pure CSS to li item :

```
.social-nav-item:hover{
  width:200px !important;
  margin-left:-150px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.
Also when I saw your Pure CSS to li item I tried to add it to my hover selector and it worked. It seems that my problem was in `margin-right: 0px` when I changed it to `margin-left: -150px` like you did everything worked fine as it should have.